# Enumerate and remove third party keyboard event bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

Using Chrome, Tampermonkey and jQuery - I would like to discover and remove key event bindings on a third party website.

I have tried to bind (over them) and prevent propagation using:

```
,_cancel:function(e){
  //console.log('keyProcessed');
  e.cancelBubble = true; // IE4+
  try {
    e.keyCode = 0;
  } catch (e) {
  } // IE5
  if (window.event) {e.returnValue = false; } // IE6
  if (e.preventDefault) {e.preventDefault(); } // moz/opera/konqueror
  if (e.stopPropagation) {e.stopPropagation(); } // all
  return false;
}
```

... but the key still fires.

I have tried enumerating elements with jQuery:

```
$('*').each(function(){
  if(this.onkeydown){
    console.log(this.tagName,this.onkeydown);
  }
});
```

... which gives no results for `keydown` `keyup` or `keypress`

I have also tried

```
$('*').unbind();
```

**How can I enumerate and kill bindings?**

Comment: if the bindings are made on elements and not `document` or `body` could try `$('body').html( $('body').html() )`. This would remove any external listeners. If there are inline event handlers can remove them with `removeAttr`. Without knowing more about page this is simply a suggestion, not a sure fire fix

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, but that would destroy the whole app. The url is conceptboard.com

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated

Before click at `button` , default action at `input` element is to input text ;  following click at `button` , `evt.preventDefault()` called , text prevented from being input at element.

Try

```
var events = ["keydown", "keyup", "keypress"];
$.each($("*"), function (index, elem) {
    if ($._data(elem, "events") != undefined) {
        // check `elem` for `keydown`, `keyup`, `keypress` `events`  
        if (new RegExp(events.join("|")).test(
            Object.keys($._data(elem, "events")))) {
            $.each(events, function (key, val) {
                // do stuff at `value` having `events`
                // call `evt.preventDefault` at `elem` 
                // having `keydown`, `keyup`, `keypress` `events` `events`
                $(elem).on(val, function(evt) {
                  evt.preventDefault()
                })
            })
        }
    };
});
```

```js
$(function () {
    
    $("input:eq(0)").on("keyup", function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
    $("input:eq(1)").on("keydown", function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
      $("input:eq(2)").on("keypress", function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
    $("button").on("click", function() {
    var events = ["keydown", "keyup", "keypress"];
    $.each($("*"), function (index, elem) {
        if ($._data(elem, "events") != undefined) {
            if (new RegExp(events.join("|")).test(
            Object.keys($._data(elem, "events")))) {
                $.each(events, function (key, val) {
                    $(elem).on(val, function(evt) {
                      evt.preventDefault()
                    })
                })
            }
        };
    });
    })
})
```

```css
input:nth-of-type(1) {
    width : 50px;
    height : 50px;
    background : blue;
}
input:nth-of-type(2) {
    display : block;
    width : 50px;
    height : 50px;
    background : yellow;
}
input:nth-of-type(3) {
    display : block;
    width : 50px;
    height : 50px;
    background : orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click to remove keydown, keyup, keypress events below</button><br />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```